# Restarting a kubernetes pod from another pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argo-events

I'm trying to use argo events to trigger a workflow where I push changes to a database, then I have to restart certain pods so that changes are taken into consideration. I know how to use argo to create kubernetes objects, but I don't know how I can use this to restart a pod from within a kubernetes object. Alternatively I can also launch a pod from within argo and its container would restart a docker container, is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can a do zero downtime rolling update via [argo rollouts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/deployment-concepts/#rolling-update).

A RollingUpdate slowly replaces the old version with the new version. As the new version comes up, the old version is scaled down in order to maintain the overall count of the application. This is the default strategy of the deployment object

Argo Rollouts also supports Canary and BlueGreen.